# Cannot see option to create Powercenter Repository service or Integration service

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to create service but it's not display in dropdown. Any idea why the option to create service is not there in the drop down menu?

**Attached snapshot for reference.**

[image: Unable to create Repository or Integration service]

Comment: Seems like a licence issue. Can you check or share some details?

Comment: @Maciejg I had downloaded the Informatica server installation package from *edelivery.oracle.com*, which gives a never expiring licence. 
PFA image from link for reference to check which package I downloaded and installed(highlighted) out of the three available packages, please suggest which one I should have downloaded. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ra9no2amiHDBZuzK6rsPJDYuHIM0R3XX)

Comment: Thw installation is fine. AFAIR you need to register the licence in Admin Console. Verify that or share a screen with licence details.

Comment: Click on [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YhAxOeGm6thnWffdJFRK9cLomjjQxi3G) for  licence details. Let me know if anymore detail is needed.

Comment: Check Assigned Services

Comment: No Service has been assigned the licence as I am not bale to create any Service. click on [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tFhGfO8wW1ArPz0sA4rmC4uc_Uf9POck) for image

Comment: Still looks to me as a licence issue, but that's just a feeling. I can't explain this nor do I understand the nature of it. I'm sorry, but I don't have other ideas then just add your licence again or re-install the server and check for installation errors while creating the domain (check the log files).